# Is there exist $w\neq0\in \mathbb R^4$ such that $Aw=Bw=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B\in M_{5\times4}(\mathbb{R})$ given that for $. v=\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
-1 \\
3 \\
1
\end{array}\right), u=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right)$ $Av=Au=0$
in addition it is also given

that $spanRow(B)=\{(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)\}$

does exist $w\neq0\in \mathbb R^4$ such that  $Aw=Bw=0$?

So I assume the idea is to use the equality $$dim(N(A))=n-rank(A)$$ for a general $m\times n$ matrix.

I undestand that dim(N(A) is at least 2 and I also understand that rank (B) is exactly 2 wich means that $$dim(N(B))\leq dim(N(A))$$ but I dont undersant how to procced from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span of the rows of $B$ is precisely the span of the columns of $B^T$ or in other words Im$(B^T)$. Now we have that
$$\text{Im}(B^T) = N(B)^\perp$$
Proof: if $y \in$ Im$(B^T)$, i.e. $y=A^Tx$ and $z$ lies in $N(B)$ then we have
$$y^Tz = (B^Tx)^Tz = x^TBz=0$$ so y is orthogonal to the nullspace of $B$. And if $y$ is orthogonal to Im$(B^T)$ that is $y^TB^Tx=0$ for all $x$ then we have $(By)^Tx=0$ for all $x$ which gives us $By=0$ by choosing $x$ to be the unit vectors. Therefore $y \in N(B)$.

Therefore we get $N(B)$ by finding the orthogonal complement of the span of the rows of $B$. Finding the orthogonal complement is equal to solving the system of linear equations
$$x+2y+3z+4w=0$$
$$5x+6y+7z+8w=0$$
We get two linear independent solutions (i.e. two free variables) and one possible basis of $N(B)$ is then
$$N(B) = \text{span}(t_1=(1,-1,-1,1),t_2= (3,-5,1,1))$$

We now want to check if there is a vector s.t. $Aw=Bw=0$ so we are looking for a vector that lies in $N(A) \cap N(B)$ and is not zero. Now if there was no such vector $w$, it would be true that dim$(N(A)) + $ dim$(N(B))=4$ because they would only have the zero vector in common (this is called a direct sum then). But if we take our two vectors spanning $N(B)$ and the vectors $u,v$ that lie in $N(A)$ into a matrix the rank of that matrix is only $3$, meaning there is a non-trivial linear combination of $u,v$ and the two vectors spanning $N(B)$ that gives zero, say
$$at_1+bt_2+cu+dv=0 \Leftrightarrow at_1+bt_2 = -cu-dv$$
which gives you a vector that lies in both $N(B)$ and $N(A)$ since the left side lies in $N(B)$ and the right side lies in $N(A)$. Because $t_1, t_2$ are linearly independent either $a$ or $b$ will be $\ne 0$ (that follows from the fact that $u,v$ are also linearly independent). Therefore this gives a vector $w$ that satisfies $Aw=Bw=0$. You can do the calculation in your head or with a computer by solving $(t_1|t_2|u|v)x=0$. One possible answer to that problem is $x=(-1,0,-1,2)$ or in other words:
$$-t_1 = u-2v$$
and therefore $w=(-1,1,1,-1)$ satisfies $Aw=Bw=0$.